# How can I skip GitHub workflow for external collaborators?

Tags: github-actions

We have a GitHub workflow for end-to-end testing. The tests require some API keys that are stored as repo secrets and exposed to the workflow. GitHub helpfully doesn‘t expose the secrets if the workflow is triggered by an external collaborator, so that untrusted parties cannot steal our API tokens through a malicious PR. Is there a way to skip the whole end-to-end workflow for these users? So far we skip the main step using an `if` rule and a special secret:

```yaml
name: E2E Tests
on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      SECRETS_SET: ${{ secrets.SECRETS_SET }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn install
      - name: Install Playwright Browsers
        run: npx playwright install --with-deps
      - name: Run Playwright tests
        # Only run this step if repo secrets are exposed
        if: ${{ env.SECRETS_SET != '' }}
        run: yarn test:e2e
```

But it would be much nicer if the workflow didn’t run at all.

Comment: I don't know about any native solution for this behavior ([only through commit messages](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/skipping-workflow-runs)). A workaround could be to use a setup job or an intermediate workflow to check if the PR author is part of the organization / team, and then trigger the end-to-end testing workflow only if that condition is true.

Comment: What are the permissions regarding write access and forking for that repo for external collaborators?